# GPU Issue Tensorflow 2.4.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I would like **to train a Tensorflow model** **by using my GPU**

I'm using :

```
tensorboard                        2.4.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit             1.8.0
tensorflow-estimator               2.4.0
tensorflow-gpu                     2.4.1
cuda                               11.0
cdnn                               8.0.4
gpu                                RTX 3060 Laptop 6Gb
Nvidia FrameView SDK               1.1.4923.29548709
Nvidia Graphics Drivers            461.72
Nvidia PhysX                       9.19.0218
Python                             3.8.5
IDE                                Spyder 4.2.1
OS                                 Windows 10 LTSC-2019 (modified)
```

**What did I do before posting this help ?**

1/ I've installed Nvidia Graphics Drivers

2/ I've followed this Tensorflow tutorial : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

So I've copied cuda folder from cdnn download archive in C:\tools\

I've also added all variables required to Path

[image]

3/ Tried to train my model (all works if I'm using CPU instead) :

```py
with tf.device("/GPU:0"):
    history = model.fit(images, imagesID, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2)
```

Error :

```
2021-03-14 15:07:16.145096: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:336] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2021-03-14 15:07:16.145335: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:340] Error retrieving driver version: Unimplemented: kernel reported driver version not implemented on Windows
2021-03-14 15:07:16.146411: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:336] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2021-03-14 15:07:16.146595: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:340] Error retrieving driver version: Unimplemented: kernel reported driver version not implemented on Windows
2021-03-14 15:07:16.146845: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1763] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops_fused_impl.h:697 : Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
```

So I've found on the Internet this : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45779

Thus, I've implemented this code at the top to limit GPU memory :

```py
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
```

Error :

```
Physical devices cannot be modified after being initialized
```

So I've found this : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25138

```py
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.2
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

But I still have the same error :

```
2021-03-14 15:07:16.145096: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:336] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
...
```

I'm completely lost because I have a lack of knowledges about Tensorflow-GPU errors...

Detail of all logs is here : https://pastebin.com/Xtsv3mLe

I'm not very good at writing posts, I hope I was clear enough.

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: So i've uninstalled 2.4.1 Tensorflow GPU for the 2.2.0
Here is the error : https://pastebin.com/XLFufzjZ
I've tried to change names of lib in bin cuda folder but still has this error...

Comment: try installing the same version of estimator as tensorflow. also are you using conda? i usually install tensorflow 2.4 with pip everything else with conda. conda install cudatoolkit is great. you can just pick the version and you can do conda install cudnn and it all just works well. This article may help you https://towardsdatascience.com/managing-cuda-dependencies-with-conda-89c5d817e7e1 looking over it I think it has all the info you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Cuda 11.0 not 11.1. You can get more information on what you need here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu. This may be a lot more helpful than reading the install guide, although you should, https://alejandro-gc.medium.com/setting-up-your-gpu-for-tensorflow-2-4-2021-d98cac79a686.